# How to add kotlin coroutines to Spring graphql API?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, kotlin-coroutines

I have a spring-boot project with usage of spring-graphql. Simple controller example below.

In it there's an invocation of business logic, CrudRepository, etc.

**How do I integrate Kotlin coroutines with Spring graphql APIs?** Preferably all the way to the DB

I tried searching for such a solution but couldn't find one using `spring-graphql`.

I've found an alternative solution by expedia, but without `spring-graphql`, so the question is still open...

Thanks.

```
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.MutationMapping
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

@Controller
class MyController(
    @QueryMapping(value = "getSomething")
    fun getSomething(){
        // ...
    }
}
```